# Angular 2 not displaying data from HTTP

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, http

I'm doing an HTTP request using Angular 2, but the results aren't being displayed. I have the following service:

```
getData() {
  return this.http.get(this.api)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here's my `AppComponent`:

```
info: any;
error: any;

constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

getData() {
  this.appService
    .getData()
    .then(response => this.info = response)
    .catch(error => this.error = error);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}
```

On my template, I'm calling `{{info.fields.id}}` but it gives me an error: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

I also created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g0WwYHdnuYUq1JHRN40G?p=preview) to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Because you are trying to retrieve data when it's not ready (not yet returned from http call). Use safe operator instead in your view: `fruit: {{info?.data?.fruit}}`

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip. Is it a good practice, though? It feels weird to me. :P

Comment: All things were invented for some reasons, weren't they? Another approach is to wrap it with `<div *ngIf="info">` to make sure the `info` is available before your code is called. The gist is to ensure the readiness of data before processing it.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Thanks, again. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the safe navigation (Elvis) operator in your template, for example `fruit: {{info?.data?.fruit}}`.  You can find more information about the safe operator [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)

This is needed because your service is returning a promise.  In the getData() method of your controller, you are using that promise and with .then() you're setting the info property on the controller.  The problem is that the view is rendering before your promise is completely resolved.